# Sourcing a through-hole T-Connector male/female part for children's ride-on toy

Tags: identification, components, adapter

I am having difficulty finding the through hole version of these "T-Connectors" as I've been able to identify from blog posts.

The type of adapter used can be seen in this image below and it is for connecting the power source and brushed motors for a kid's ride-on car toy.

[image: picture of t-adapter on PCB]

**Does anyone have a common part number or manufacturer that I can source these from?**

I am specifically looking for both male and female through-hole parts.

Comment: Google faston pcb

Comment: Search for PCB through hole tabs. The female parts are usually spade crimps.

Comment: Thanks folks! This helped a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Google search suggested by [D Duck](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/174591/d-duck) in the comment section (thanks!), the connector is a:

**250 FASTON TAB TPBR**

The product spec sheet in question is:
https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-63900-1.html

And the dimensions and drawings can be found [here](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=showdoc&DocId=Customer%20Drawing%7F63900%7FD%7Fpdf%7FEnglish%7FENG_CD_63900_D_baseFilename.pdf%7F63900-1).

For future Google searchers and question indexing, the board being referenced in the question and picture is `JR1922RXS-D2`. It is a controller board for a kid's ride-on car toy.